# Need help splitting rows in Excel with Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that I'm trying to get into a specific format. Currently, my line items are all on the same row. Here's the current version vs the way I need it to look like on different sheets - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CH_zI6Waky0YCcArCvjAa4x3YbEt8rMEbybZRI-dOoc/edit#gid=0

The problem with my code is it creates a total 9 lines for each ad group. It should only have 3 rows per ad group.

[image]

```
Sub SplitAds()

Dim thissheet As Worksheet
Set thissheet = ActiveSheet

Sheets.Add
Dim newsheet As Worksheet
Set newsheet = ActiveSheet

'Copy Headers
thissheet.Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy
newsheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Dim newrow As Long
For x = 0 To thissheet.Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Row

thissheet.Range("A2:C2").Offset(x, 0).Copy
'Copy & Paste A:C
newsheet.Range("A2").Offset(newrow, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
newsheet.Range("A2").Offset(newrow + 1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
newsheet.Range("A2").Offset(newrow + 2, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
'Set Type
newsheet.Range("L2").Offset(newrow, 0).Value = thissheet.Range("L2").Offset(x, 0).Value
newsheet.Range("L2").Offset(newrow + 1, 0).Value = thissheet.Range("L2").Offset(x, 0).Value
newsheet.Range("L2").Offset(newrow + 2, 0).Value = thissheet.Range("L2").Offset(x, 0).Value
'Set D:J on 2nd
thissheet.Range("D2:J2").Offset(x, 0).Copy
newsheet.Range("D2").Offset(newrow + 1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
'Set Keyword on 3rd
newsheet.Range("K2").Offset(newrow + 2, 0).Value = thissheet.Range("K2").Offset(x, 0).Value

newrow = newrow + 3
Next

End Sub
```

Would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: How about an example of your original data?  Preferably in your question, or with a link?  But I'll guess that you need to increment your counter `X` by three instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your are incrementing your row one at a time, while your `newrow` is incrementing three at a time.  As a result, you are creating three rows for every one.

You can resolve this, probably with a `step 3` in your `for` loop, or by changing the `for` to a `while` and then manually incrementing by three, the way you do with `newrows`:

```
Sub SplitAds()

  Dim thissheet, newsheet As Worksheet
  Set thissheet = ActiveSheet
  Set newsheet = Sheets.Add
  Dim x, maxRow, newrow As Long

  'Copy Headers
  thissheet.Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy
  newsheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

  maxRow = thissheet.Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Row - 1

  While x < maxRow

    thissheet.Range("A2:C2").Offset(x, 0).Copy
    'Copy & Paste A:C
    newsheet.Range("A2").Offset(newrow, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    newsheet.Range("A2").Offset(newrow + 1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    newsheet.Range("A2").Offset(newrow + 2, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    'Set Type
    newsheet.Range("L2").Offset(newrow, 0).Value = thissheet.Range("L2").Offset(x, 0).Value
    newsheet.Range("L2").Offset(newrow + 1, 0).Value = thissheet.Range("L2").Offset(x, 0).Value
    newsheet.Range("L2").Offset(newrow + 2, 0).Value = thissheet.Range("L2").Offset(x, 0).Value
    'Set D:J on 2nd
    thissheet.Range("D2:J2").Offset(x, 0).Copy
    newsheet.Range("D2").Offset(newrow + 1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    'Set Keyword on 3rd
    newsheet.Range("K2").Offset(newrow + 2, 0).Value = thissheet.Range("K2").Offset(x, 0).Value

    x = x + 3
    newrow = newrow + 3
  Wend

End Sub
```